# Python: Where do I add new line breaks while creating a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, newline

I am new to programming in general and very new to Python.  I have a csv list that is read into python, shuffled, and then written out in a different order.

In its current state, it prints out a long list of the items that are shuffled.  I need to have them each printed onto a new row instead.  To do that I understand I need to add \n somewhere, but I don't know where.  Should I add it to the section of the code where the list is created in the first place, or where the csv file is written?  I am guessing the latter, so here is the relevant code, but I can paste more if necessary:

```
make_list = csv.writer(open('026a_te.csv', 'wb'))
make_list.writerow(list_a)
```

Where do I add \n so that each element of list_a is written to a new row in the output file 026a_te.csv?

Comment: Did you try to put /n in different places? See what it does? You need to format your output figure out how

Comment: Yes, I've tried it in a few places and haven't found the correct one yet.

Comment: If you're only writing a single column, the `csv` module is probably overkill anyway (unless you need its quoting capabilities).

Comment: I have two, I just wanted to keep the question as simple and general as possible.

Answer (score 5):

You're only writing a single row to the output csv, so naturally it's going to be all on one line.

You should have a list of lists to write using `writerows` instead of `writerow`, or you should be in a loop that calls `writerow` multiple times. The newlines will be added for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I ended up needing writerows after all.